# I am getting "cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting this error. I am trying to output names present in the array on the html document but I am not able to do it. I tried placing script tag below body but still not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Callback Function</h1> 

    <ul class"people"> </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="callme.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// get a reference to the 'ul'
const ul = document.querySelector('.people');

//I am trying to read the people on to the html code
const people = ['mario', 'luigi', 'ryu', 'shaun', 'chun-li'];
let html = ` `;
people.forEach(function(person){
  html += `<li> style="color: purple">${person}</li>`;
});


console.log("hellow");
ul.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 6):

There's an error in your HTML.
Try this:

```
<ul class="people"> </ul>
```

There was an = sign missing between class and "people".

Answer (score 0):

small error in html, js markup added correct one below, your list will print correct.

```js
// get a reference to the 'ul'
const ul = document.querySelector('.people');

//I am trying to read the people on to the html code
const people = ['mario', 'luigi', 'ryu', 'shaun', 'chun-li'];
let html = ` `;
people.forEach(function(person){
  html += `<li style="color: purple">${person}</li>`;
});


console.log("hellow");
ul.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Callback Function</h1> 

    <ul class="people"> </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="callme.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```